# OCaml Binary Tree Mirror Image

Tags: ocaml, binary-tree, mirror

I'm learning OCaml for a class, and was given an assignment of computing the mirror image of a binary tree. I'm quite stuck and am not sure how to even start...

```
type btree = Empty | Node of int * btree * btree
;;

let mirror : btree -> btree
  = fun t -> (* Code *)
```

Sample input:

```
let tree1 = Node(1, Node(2, Node(3, Empty, Empty), Empty), Node(4, Empty, Empty))
;;
```

Sample output:

```
mirror tree1 = Node(1, Node(4, Empty, Empty), Node(2, Empty, Node(3, Empty, Empty)))
;;
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: start with something simple : what could be the code to mirror Node(1,Empty, Empty) ? Node(1,Node(2,Empty,Empty),Empty) ? and then generalize (see the answer from Jin below). Post your trials - you will then have more chance to get help.

Comment: Normally in ML you'd use pattern matching, but it's interesting how you (or your instructor) is giving the sample that resembles [s-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `match` feature.

You can `match` on the value's structure as defined by its type. In your example, a value of the `btree` type is created with either the `Empty` constructor or a tuple constructor of `Node of int * btree * btree`. You should end up with something like this:

```ml
...
match t with
| Node (num, lt, rt) -> (* do something to switch the subtrees, and mirror the subtrees themselves *)
| Empty -> (* do nothing *)
...
```

and since the `mirror` function is of type `btree -> btree`, each of your match cases must return a valid value of type `btree`.

See: http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/data_types_and_matching.html#Pattern-matching-on-datatypes